# How do I connect to a docker postgreSQL container from outside the host

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have a docker container running postgresql connected to another container (webmapping server) on an ubuntu host. I would like to connect to my database from outside the host (another machine on the same network).

I'm able to connect to the database from the host (PGadmin), from the other container but not from outside the host (through public IP)
[error screenshot on PGadmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPzdc.png)

how should I fix this ?

many thanks, Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Solved it by myself : I had to specify 0.0.0.0:5432:5432 to make it reachable from any IP, public or local.

Many thanks to Hans for helping

Answer (score 0):

You need to map port 5432 on the container to a port on the host and connect through that.

Let's say you want to use port 55432 on the host. Then you'd add the parameter `-r 55432:5432` to your docker run command and then connect to port 55432 on your docker host machine.

You also need to allow incoming connections on port 55432 on your host machine's firewall to be able to connect from outside the host.

Comment: this is exactly what I did and it works on the host. I doesn't work from outside...

Comment: You might need to open up the host firewall to allow connections on the port.

Answer (score 0):

Using pgcl utilities in host:
Public IP address: xx.xx.xx.xx
pgcli -h xx.xx.xx.xx -p 5432 or 5416(user defined) -U postgres

Server: PostgreSQL 15.1 (Debian 15.1-1.pgdg110+1)
Version: 3.5.0
Home: http://pgcli.com
postgres@10:postgres>

-----------+-------+----------+------------+------------+-------------------+
| Name      | Owner | Encoding | Collate    | Ctype      | Access privileges |
|-----------+-------+----------+------------+----|
| postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 |             |
| template0 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =c/postgres          |

Comment: postgres@10:postgres> \l
+-----------+-------+----------+------------+------------+-------------------+
| Name      | Owner | Encoding | Collate    | Ctype      | Access privileges |
|-----------+-------+----------+------------+------------+-------------------|
         |
| postgres  | azmat | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | <null>            |
| template0 | azmat | UTF8     | en_US.utf8 | en_US.utf8 | =c/azmat          |

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).